# Service giving null pointer in a Component

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, caching

I am setting cache in a Service and then calling that service to retrieve the cache as shown below:

MenuService (annotated with @Service) this is where cache is set

```
@Autowired
APIClient apiClient  \\feign client calling to another api

@Cacheable("disclaimerList")
public List<MyObjectDTO> getList(){
return apiClient.getListFromDb(); \\gets the list and stores in cache
}
```

MenuHelper (annotated with @Component) this is where cache is retrieved

```
@Autowired
   MenuService menuService;
@Autowired
   CacheManager cacheManager;
private static MenuService menuServiceImpl;
private static CacheManager cacheManagerService;

@PostConstruct
void init(){
\\initializing variables here

MenuHelper.menuServiceImpl = menuService;
MenuHelper.cacheManagerService = cacheManager;
}

MenuHelper() {}

private static List<MyObjectDTO> getCacheList(){
if(cacheManager == null){
menuService.getList(); \\stores the cache; Null pointer exception occurs here!!
}
Cache cache = cacheManager.get("MyList"); \\getting the cache
Object obj = cache.get(SimpleKey.EMPTY).get(); \\getting cache stored with "EMPTY" key
List<MyObjectDTO> returnList = modelMapper.map(obj, new TypeToken<List<MyObjectDTO>>(){}.getType()); \\mapping it to a List of MyObjectDTO
return returnList;
}
```

When **menuHelper.getCacheList()** gets called above, it throws a null pointer exception where **menuService.getCache()** is being called. I am guessing it's because menuService is not getting autowired. I have set the value in the @PostConstruct method but it's not working. Help/Guidance/Pointers will be much appreciated!

Comment: `getCacheList()` it is a `static` method. Does the code compiles with `menuService` as instance variable? When `menuHelper.getCacheList()` is called?

Comment: It does compile but when menuHelper.getCacheList() is called it throws a null pointer exception.

Comment: Can you add sample from where it is called `menuHelper.getCacheList()`?

Comment: It's called from a static method as well:                                                   
 ```private static setVariables()                                                                                       List<ObjectDTO> setThisList = getCacheList(); ```

Comment: The issue can be related to fact that you are trying to use static methods and autowire beans to static fields. Spring use to inject dependence into instance fields.

Comment: Yes that's i am leaning towards as well. Any idea how I can autowire beans into static fields which will be used by static methods?

Comment: I'm not sure that it is even possible to autowire beans in static fields. May I ask you why do you need them to be static?

Comment: I am adding a feature in a legacy code and all the methods are static in the code. Hence need static variables. to pass into that method.

Comment: Try to declare 
`MenuHelper.menuServiceImpl = menuService; `
at the beggining of the method `getCacheList`
and put a breakpoint at this line... see if when it's processed it is null.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve the error by first autowiring MenuHelper in a service that was calling `getCacheList()` method. Then I called `init()` method to initialize the static variables (VERY IMPORTANT STEP) and removed "static" identifier from the `getCacheList()` method.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).